# Angular group by JSON multiple key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am using Angular field groupBy https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby , it is working like a charm for a simple JSON file but here my problem

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: ['alpha','beta']},
];
```

I want to have :

```
  Group name: alpha
    * player: Gene
    * player: George
  Group name: beta
    * player: George
```

But with my code I have :

```
  Group name: alpha
    * player: Gene
  Group name: alpha,beta
    * player: George
```

My code is the same as the example

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
    Group name: {{ key }}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="player in value">
        player: {{ player.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be really appreciated,
Thank you very much

Comment: Looks like groupBy filter doesn't accept an array as input.

Comment: It's not the same as the example you have an array `['alpha','beta']` and a string `'alpha'`

Comment: Yes but what would be the solution if a player plays at team alpha & beta at the same time ?

Answer (score 1):

iterate over the team object inside player json and then pass it to the filter bcoz it does not accept array

Comment: Thank you very much, but could you elaborate more please ?